# RegEx: How to extract a value/number from a pattern and replace it with something else?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, replace, preg-replace-callback

For instance I have this piece of data:

```
array(
    1 => 'Metallica',
    2 => 'Megadeth',
    3 => 'Anthrax',
    4 => 'Slayer',
    5 => 'Black Sabbath',
);
```

And I have this piece of text:

> My first favorite band is: **#band{2}**, and after that it's: **#band1**. My
>   over-all first metal band was: **#band{5}**, and I sometimes enjoy
>   headbaning while listening to: **#band3** or **#band{4}**.

So after the RegEx, it should look like this:

> My first favorite band is: **Megadeth**, and after that it's: **Metallica**.
>   My over-all first metal band was: **Black Sabbath**, and I sometimes enjoy
>   headbaning while listening to: **Anthrax** or **Slayer**.

So, I need a pattern/example how can I extract numbers from these two patterns:

> **#band{NUMERIC-ID}** or **#bandNUMERIC-ID**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for regular expressions, just use `str_replace()`:

```
$map = array();
foreach ($bands as $k => $v){
    $map["#band".$k] = $v;
    $map["#band{".$k."}"] = $v;
}

$out = str_replace(array_keys($map), $map, $text);
```

A demo: http://codepad.org/uPqGXGg6

If you want to use regular expressions:

```
$out = preg_replace_callback('!\#band((\d+)|(\{(\d+)\}))?!', 'replace_band', $text);

function replace_band($m){
    $band = $GLOBALS['bands'][$m[2].$m[4]];
    return $band ? $band : 'UNKNOWN BAND';
}
```

A demo: http://codepad.org/2hNEqiCk

[edit] updated for multiple forms of the token to replace

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$txt = 'your text with bands';
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    $txt = preg_replace('/#band'.$key.'([^0-9])/', $val.'$1', $txt);
    $txt = preg_replace('/#band{'.$key.'}/', $val.'$1', $txt);
}

//detect the error
if(preg_match('/#band[^0-9]+/', $txt) || preg_match('/#band{[^0-9]+}/', $txt){
  //error!!!
}

//replace the non found bands with a string
$txt = preg_replace('/#band[^0-9]+/', 'failsafe', $txt);
$txt = preg_replace('/#band{[^0-9]+}/', 'failsafe', $txt);
```

Comment: how can I add failsafe here, if the index does not exist in my array?

Comment: what should happen if the index doesn't exist?

Comment: well it's up to me to handle that error... but how would you handle that expection from your perspective of code?